# the best way to leverage an HtmlDocument object from the HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-agility-pack

i have a code snippet that load an html document and return for further manipulation.

```
  private HtmlDocument LoadPage(string path)
    {
        var web = new HtmlWeb();
        var doc = web.Load(url + path);
        return doc;
    }
```

I created smaller methods to extract the information I want in the following way :

```
    public string getNameInfo(String path)
    {
        HtmlDocument doc = LoadPage(path);
        string tag = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='header_action']/div[1]/div[2]/h2").InnerText.Replace("\n", String.Empty);
        return tag;
    }
```

I have another method that returns another tag I want to inform

```
  public string getCodeInfo(String path)
    {
        HtmlDocument doc = LoadPage(path);
        string tag = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='header_action']/div[1]/div[2]/h1").InnerText.Replace("\n", String.Empty);
        return tag;
    }
```

Today I can extract the information I want, but I would like to reuse the HtmlDocument that has already been consulted and enjoy a single download from the page.

I tried some solutions but I couldn't, is there any way to take a single HtmlDocument and break it down into smaller functions to populate my variables without needing to do multiple queries on the loading method. The proposal would be to perform a single query on the LoadPage method and use it for all minor functions.

Thanks for listening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if i've understood it correctly. Why don't you simply reuse the `HtmlDocument`?

```
public string GetNameInfo(HtmlDocument doc)
{
    string tag = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='header_action']/div[1]/div[2]/h2").InnerText.Replace("\n", String.Empty);
    return tag;
}

public string GetCodeInfo(HtmlDocument doc)
{
    string tag = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='header_action']/div[1]/div[2]/h1").InnerText.Replace("\n", String.Empty);
    return tag;
}
```

You just need to load it once and then pass it to the methods.

Another way is: store the `HtmlDocument` in a property or field of your class, initialize it with `LoadPage` and access it in `GetNameInfo` and `GetCodeInfo`, remove the parameter in these methods.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, my friend. I apologize because my English is very bad, but you understood correctly what I meant, I leave my sincere thanks